# Connected components of a space $X$ are disjoint

Tags: general-topology

$C\subseteq X$ is called a component of $X$ is $C$ is a maximal connected subset of $X$.

A theorem says, let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation defined as $x\sim y$ iff $x$ and $y$ are in the same component (it's easy to check that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation). Then the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are the components of $X$.

To show that the equivalence classes are precisely the components of $X$, I think it suffices to show if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are different components of $X$, then $C_1\cap C_2=\emptyset$.

So suppose for a contradiction $C_1\cap C_2\neq\emptyset$. Clearly one cannot be a subset of another, otherwise one of them can't be a component since it would violate maximality. So there exist some $x\in C_1\setminus C_2$ and $y\in C_2\setminus C_1$. How can I get a contradiction from this?

Comment: If $C_1, C_2$ are two connected component of a point $x$, $C_1 \cap C_2$ is a connected set which contains $x_1$. So $C_1 \cup C_2$ would be a connected set which contains both $C_1$ and $C_2$, contradicting that $C_1, C_2$ are maximal. (Here, I used that the union of two connected set with a non-empty intersection is connected.)

Comment: Do you mind to prove that the union of two connected sets with non-empty intersection is connected?

Comment: Sure, if $(U,V)$ is a separation of $X_1 \cup X_2$ we can't have $U = X_1, V = X_2$ or vice-versa as by hypothesis they do intersect. If follows that e.g $U \cap X_1, V \cap X_1$ are not empty and so we have an induced separation of $X_1$ which contradicts that $X_1$ is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't you arrived at the solution already.  If $z \in C_1 \cap C_2$, then  x~z and y~z. Therefore, y~x from the definition of the classes.  So you have a contradiction as this shows that neither $C_1$ nor $C_2$ is maximally connected and are thus not components.

Comment: Oh thanks, the answer is right in front of me! But still I'd like to prove that the union of two connected sets with non-empty intersection is connected.

Comment: @SidCaroline see my answer.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction here. For all we know from this, couldn't $x$ and $y$ be in a connected component that is not a superset of neither $C_1$, nor $C_2$?

Answer (score 2):

Basic fact: if $C,D$ are connected subsets of $X$ and $C \cap D\neq \emptyset$ then $C \cup D$ is connected.

Proof: suppose that $C \cup D = U \cup V$ where $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and $U,V$ are open in $C \cup D$. Let $p \in C \cap D$. This $p$ either lies in $U$ or $V$, say in $U$ for definiteness.

Then $C= (U \cap C) \cup (V \cap C)$ and both sets $U \cap C$ and $V \cap C$ are open in $C$, and they are still disjoint.
As $C$ is connected, this cannot be a real disconnection of $C$, so one set is empty, the other the whole set. $U \cap C$ contains $p$, so that is the non-empty one. So $U \cap C = C$, which means that $C \subseteq U$.
Then also $D = (U \cap D) \cup (V \cap D)$ which for the same reason cannot be a disconnection of $D$, and again $p \in U \cap D$, so $U \cap D = D$ and $D \subseteq V$. Hence $C \cup D = U $ and so $V = \emptyset$. This shows that $C \cup D$ is connected.

Now, if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two components, if they intersect, then $C_1 \cup C_2$ is connected by the previous fact. And as $C_1 \subseteq C_1 \cup C_2$ and $C_1$ is a maximal connected set, $C_1 = C_1 \cup C_2 = C_2$ (the last by maximality of $C_2$. But this means that $C_1 = C_2$. So if components intersect they are equal, which is another way of saying different components are disjoint.

Comment: I don't understand why you did posted it as an answer as it is more or less exactly what I said in comments before. (This is not an agressive message, I just don't understand).

Comment: The OP remarked in the comment that he would like to see the proof of the intersection property.

Comment: I also answered to this few minutes after (but maybe it was just a bad timing I guess). And anyways I really appreciate your answers in general, so +1.